# @RolesAllowed annotation always throw 403 error with Keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm a new one in Spring boot and have maybe a stupid question.
I have a simple spring boot rest api application with spring security and oauth2. Outh2 broker is Keycloak
So my security filter looks like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityAdditionalConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(
                SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

Also I enable global method security

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
}
```

But when I try to add @RolesAllowed('admin') to my controller method I always get 403 forbidden error
Without annotations all works fine, without token I get 401 and if token expired 403.
This is example of my jwt

```
{
  
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "admin"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "edge_client": {
      "roles": [
        "cli_admin"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "profile web-origins email",
  "email_verified": false,
  "name": "John Spartan",
  "groups": [
    "admin"
  ],
  "preferred_username": "test_admin",
  "given_name": "John",
  "family_name": "Spartan"
}
```

Comment: May be the user you use to make your test has no `admin` role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/dfaf251970e1fb555219be4e8e27a5ac7e7f0ac7/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.java) is responsible for getting authorities. By default it is looking for `scope` or `scp` claims in `jwt`. In your case you have `"scope": "profile web-origins email"`. After that it prefixes every authority with `DEFAULT_AUTHORITY_PREFIX`  equals to `SCOPE_`. I think when you will debug your `Authentication` object from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` authorities returned by its `getAuthorities()` will be equals to `SCOPE_profile`, `SCOPE_web-origins` and `SCOPE_email`. You should change your code to:

```java
.oauth2ResourceServer()
.jwt(customizer -> {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    //write your own Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter 
    //and override Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) to get roles from
    //realm_access.roles
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    customizer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter)
})
```

or use [Keycloak Adapter for Spring](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_boot_adapter) instead of `oauth2ResourceServer()`